# Force iPython %cd magic command to not print path

Tags: python, ipython, cd, ipython-magic

## [iPython](https://ipython.org) [`%cd` magic command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd)

Can the [`%cd` magic command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd) in [iPython](https://ipython.org) be made to not show the output path?  If you pass a relative path or start from a shortcut `~/`, this can be nice when sharing notebooks, but the output shows a full path which may not be relevant to the audience.

```
In [1]: %cd ~/GitHub/someplace
/Users/accountname/GitHub/someplace

In [2]: |
```

It would be nice to either return nothing or return the relative path...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *Quiet* iPython `%cd` magic command

The [iPython magic command provides a quiet option](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd).  Use the `-q` option to not display the output.

```
In [1]: %cd -q ~/GitHub/someplace

In [2]: |
```